# How to invert this expression involving $\tanh^{-1}$?

Tags: functions, inverse

I've got the expression:

$ x = \tanh^{-1}(p) - \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \tanh^{-1}\left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} p\right) $

How can I invert this function so I have a function $p(x)$? I thought about using angle-sum formulas for $\tanh$, but this has lead me nowhere. If it helps with anything, I only care about the inverse in the range that $p \in (-1,1)$, where $x$ is real.

Is it even possible to invert this at all?

EDIT: I have tried;

- using the angle formula $\tanh(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{\tanh(\alpha)-\tanh(\beta)}{1-\tanh(\alpha)\tanh(\beta)}$, and this leaves me with a function of $p$ to the power of $\sqrt{2/3}$, so this I can't use.
- splitting the function apart into logarithms, but I get some $p$'s to the power of $\sqrt{2/3}$ again
- putting the above into the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 - (\frac{2}{3})^n \right) \frac{p^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$, and I've tried to use reversion of series to get the inverse. I can't get this to work either.

Does any one have an alternate approach? I thought perhaps doing some kind of a "curve-fitting" in Maple, but I don't know if it is possible to get an exact answer with a method like this.

some context: I'm really just looking for the solution to the DE $\frac{dp}{dx}=(p^2-1)(2p^2-3)$.

Comment: At a glance, I'd say "probably not".

Comment: I think your expression is equivalent to $e^{2x} =  \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}p}{1 - \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}p} \right)^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}  \left( \frac{1 + p}{1 - p} \right)   $ and the right hand side of that does not look easy to invert. Near $p=0$ you may have $x \approx \frac53 p$ and so near $x=0$ you might have $p \approx \frac35 x$

Comment: @Henry You are correct. This first 2 terms of the series expansion are $\frac{3 y}{5}+\frac{3 y^3}{125}$.

Comment: You could get a recurrence relation for the coefficients like in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4613479/very-difficult-recurrence-relation-for-the-coefficients-of-an-ode-solution), but there probably is an explicit solution for the series coefficients for $p(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would use [Laplace inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform) or this [article’s multinomial sum to hypergeometric function method](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904) to get a single sum over [Appell $\text F_1$](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/AppellF1/07/01/01/0001/) to invert $f(x)=\tanh^{-1}(x)-a\tanh^{-1}(ax),0<a<1$. However, the Laplace transform of $f^{-1}(x)$, $\displaystyle\frac1s\int_0^1(1+t)^{-\frac s2}(1-t)^\frac s2(1-a t)^{-\frac{as}2}(1+a t)^\frac{as}2dt$, does not match the linked integral representation and the other method gives incorrect values. Alternatively, we just use [Lagrange inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem):

$$f(x)=\tanh^{-1}(x)-a\tanh^{-1}(ax)\implies f^{-1}(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^ne^{-2nx}}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\frac{(1-ax)^{a n}(x+1)^n}{(1+ax)^{an}}\right|_1$$

and apply [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) twice to get:

$$f^{-1}(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{(-1)^{m+n}(2a)^{m+1}(1-a)^{an-k}\Gamma(an+m-k)n!}{e^{2nx}(1+a)^{an+m-k}(an-k)!\Gamma(n-m)(m-k)!(m+1)!k!}$$

and sum over $k$ to get the [Gauss hypergeometric function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssHypergeometricTheorem.html):

$$\bbox[4px,border: 3px solid lightblue]{f(x)=\tanh^{-1}(x)-a\tanh^{-1}(ax)\implies f^{-1}(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{m+n} (2a)^{m+1}(1-a)^{an}\Gamma(an+m)n!}{e^{2nx}(a+1)^{an+m}\Gamma(n-m)(m+1)!(an)!m!}\,_1\text F_1\left(-m,-an;1-m-an;\frac{a+1}{a-1}\right)}$$

shown here:

[image]

Therefore, $p(x)$ is, likely at its simplest and as shown by the triple series, a three parameter hypergeometric function. When $a=\sqrt\frac23$, it is the OP’s function.

Comment: This series diverges for $x$ very close to $0$